# How to convert a string to blob/longblob in nodejs - MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, blob

I am doing a REST API with **Node.js** - **Express** and I have to store in a database an image. The type that I have to use for that is longblob. The client send me the image as a **String**, is there a way to convert that String to **blob/longblob**?

I am doing the REST API in this way:

```
router.post("/usuario/nuevoPostulante", (req, res) => {
  const { documento, nombre, direccion, myblob, correo, nacionalidad } = req.body;
  const query = `CALL add_postulante(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);`;
  mysqlConnect.query(
    query,
    [documento, nombre, direccion, myblob, correo, nacionalidad],
    (err, rows, fields) => {
      if (!err) {
        res.json({
          code: 201,
          data: {},
          message: "Se registra correctamente al usuario.",
        });
      } else {
        console.log(err);
        res.json({
          code: 409,
          data: {},
          message: "Error en la creacion del usuario",
        });
      }
    }
  );
});
```

**myblob** is the **string** I receive

Answer (score 0):

First, pass a base64 string to fetch:

```
const base64Data = "aGV5IHRoZXJl";
const base64 = await fetch(base64Data);
```

Depending on the format of the base64 string, you might need to prepend content type data. For example, a JPEG image:

```
const base64Response = await fetch(`data:image/jpeg;base64,${base64Data}`);
```

Next, convert the response to a blob:

```
const blob = await base64Response.blob();
```

That’s it! From here, you can upload it to a server, display it on the screen, and more.

Comment: Hi Vahid, thanks for your answer. I don't think I can do what you said. Could you check my question again? Because I edited it. Maybe you have another solution. :)